# Javascript timespan not returning expected result

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to get timespan/elapsed time between two dates

```
var timein = new Date(year, month, day, tihh1, timm1, 0);
var timeout = new Date(year, month, day, tohh1, tomm1, 0);

var diff = timeout.getTime() - timein.getTime();
var timespan = new Date(diff);

totalHH = parseInt(totalHH) + parseInt(timespan.getUTCHours());
totalMM = parseInt(totalMM) + parseInt(timespan.getUTCMinutes());
```

This code works but when the time in is later to time out it's not returning a negative result.

Example:

```
var timein = new Date(2015, 10, 19, 9, 0, 0); // Oct 19 2015 9:00:00
var timeout = new Date(2015, 10, 19, 8, 0, 0); // Oct 19 2015 8:00:00

// Oct 19 2015 8:00:00 - Oct 19 2015 9:00:00
```

Expected Result: -1 (Hour)

Actual Result: 23 (Hour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works as expected.

### Causes

After substraction, `diff` will be equal to `-3600000` and `timespan` will be initialized with this value.

`new Date(value)` constructor creates a `Date` object equal to the Unix epoch beginning (01/01/1970 00:00:00 UTC) plus `value` milliseconds. As `value` is negative in our case, `new Date(-3600000)` will be evaluated to `31/12/1969 23:00:00 UTC` (one hour before the Unix epoch).

Now, you apply `timespan.getUTCHours()` and it is equal to 23.

### Solution

In my opinion, the easiest way in this case is to use a simple math instead of `Date` objects, because it is not supposed to work this way.

For example, in your case, the result for dates `01 Jan 2015 00:00:00` and `03 Jan 2015 00:00:00` will be `0` while the proper answer is 48 hours.

Just calculate the values based on arithemetics, like this:

```js
function writeHHMM(timein, timeout)
{
  var totalMinutes = (timeout - timein) / 60000;

  var totalHH = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60); // Math.floor provides integer only values
  var totalMM = Math.floor(totalMinutes % 60); // and cuts off seconds
  
  document.body.innerHTML += "<br/> " + totalHH + " hours, " + totalMM + " minutes"; 
}

writeHHMM(new Date(2015, 10, 19, 9, 0, 0), new Date(2015, 10, 19, 8, 0, 0));
writeHHMM(new Date(2015, 10, 19, 9, 0, 0), new Date(2015, 10, 21, 9, 0, 0));
writeHHMM(new Date(2015, 10, 19, 9, 0, 0), new Date(2014, 7, 3, 5, 15, 13));
```

Comment: I think my question is not clear sir, i'm expecting -1 result because 8-9 = -1

Comment: But what Yeldar is saying is your code gives that result because that is how your code works, even though in your mind 8 - 9 = -1

Comment: @JohnLouieDelaCruz Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: Wow thanks! @YeldarKurmangaliyev It works now, thank you for your help :)